# MySQL datetime >= a column named "to"

Tags: mysql, datetime

I'm trying to get some data from my database in MySQL. So what I do is:

```
select * from my_table where 'to' ='0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

which give me empty set but I have some data where the column 'to' is at '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

second I tried this:

```
 select * from my_table where 'to' > NOW();
```

but I have the following error:

> ERROR 1267 (HY000): Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) and (latin1_swedish_ci,NUMERIC) for operation '>'

So in the final what I would like is

```
select * from my_table where 'to' > NOW() or 'to' = '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
```

So if I do `describe my_table;` I have:

[image]

And if I do `select * from my_table limit 10` I have:

[image]

Which mean that I have some 'to' at '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries look like this:

```
 select * from my_table where 'to' = datestamp
```

You are giving an expression comparing the text string `'to'` to the datestamp. That's making MySQL do strange things and throw errors.

Try this

```
 select * from my_table where `to` = datestamp
```

surrounding your column name with backticks.

Better yet, don't use SQL words like `to`, `from`, `where`, and so forth for column names.